# How to use for loops to generate objects in R

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap

I am attempting to use bootstrapping in R to resample a group of binary choices. I can obtain a sample of 10 "Yes" or "No" answers from the population of 50.

```
n <- 50
x <- (c(rep("YES", 25), rep("NO", 25)))
sample.1 <- sample(x,10)
(sample.1)
[1] "YES" "NO"  "NO"  "NO"  "NO"  "NO"  "NO"  "NO"  "NO"  "YES"
```

However, I need to repeat this approximately 1,000 times (or any x number of times) and store each in its own object (sample.1 will have 10 answers, sample.2 will have 10 answers, etc...)
The reason each needs to be separate is so that each can generate its own confidence interval from the proportion of "Yes" answers and the span of confidence intervals will be plotted into a histogram. 
Is this achievable with for loops? If so, how?

Comment: See `?replicate`. Also see `?apply` for what to do with the output of `replicate`.

Comment: I'm sure there's a more elegant way to do this, but if you call your vector of yeses and nos `vector` instead of `x`, then this gets you a list with 1,000 samples of 10 from it: `samples <- lapply(rep(10, times=1000), function(x) sample(vector, x))`. Then you can use `lapply` again on that list to get your summary stats, or `sapply` if you want the result to be a vector.

Comment: You are sampling without replacement. Is that really what you want? How about returning as a matrix `sample.1 <- matrix(sample(c("YES", "NO"), 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(.5, .5)), nrow=10)`  so you can do simple things like `apply(sample.1=="YES", 2, sum)`

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

data_frame(x = (c(rep("YES", 25), rep("NO", 25))) %>%
  merge(data_frame(i = 1:1000)) %>%
  group_by(i) %>%
  sample_n(10, replace = TRUE)
```

In R, merge without an index entails a cross join. This will replicate your data, then resample each replicate differently. Maybe not very efficient.